# How to not cache nonces with WP Rocket?

Tags: cache, nonce

We have a system where we pass a nonce from a PHP-script on the server to an AJAX-call running client-side, and then back again to check the validity of the request.

This nonce is cached, and we can't figure out how to exclude it. We had cache time set to 10 hours but have since reduced it to 8 hours.

But let's say the nonce is renewed at 12 AM and the cache is renewed at 10 AM, we still have six hours of the nonce not working even with 8 hours cache.

How do we fix this?

Comment: Sorry if it's an obvious answer, but it sounds like you shouldnt' be caching the Ajax/API call. So is your question how to prevent caching for a specific URL? Do you know what's caching it? Is it the browser, or do you have a caching plugin or CDN or anything else that might be doing the caching?

Comment: @mozboz - It's the plugin WP Rocket. It does not cache AJAX-calls by default, but the nonce generated is still cached. We can prevent caching for the specific URL, but then we'll stop caching all product pages in a pretty huge store, so that won't be a solution sadly. I'll look more into the AJAX-part because it sounds like this shouldn't get cached.

Comment: Yes, the AJAX request should have its own URL that needs to be not cached, which is different to the page that request loads in. Sorry if I'm stating the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the specific AJAX call URL and prevent that being cached with the WP-Rocket advanced rules settings. https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/54-exclude-pages-from-the-cache.

As per your comment, you need a strategy for not having the nonce in a file that can be cached such as javascript files, so as you said, use PHP to generate the nonce and pass it outside of the javascript file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The AJAX call is to admin-ajax.php and that is not cached by default. But the problem is using wp_localize_script to pass the nonce to the javascript file. It will be printed to the page and cached.

The solution, in this case, will be to call a PHP-function at page load to generate a new nonce and pass that to the script, avoiding the cache.

If you update your answer to also include that information I will accept it :)

Comment: @TASan have update the answer with this info, not sure how helpful that is though. i guess you figured out the problem though that the nonce was being cached in a javascript file so you can pass it elsewhere?

Comment: Yeah, wp_localize_script that is often used to pass nonces will print them out and make them cached. By instead generating the nonce outside of wp_localize_script and passing it when needed will solve it.